# dynamically generated html doesn't wrap to the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this markup is not wrapping. There's nothing special about it, except that it is generated by javascript. Here's the code. Any thoughts on why it's messing up would be welcome.

I can include the js if you need. but basically it reads the text in the textarea, extracts the words, and creates a list of words.

the style:

```
<style type="text/css">
#lorem{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
#main{

}
.word{
    margin: 5px;
}
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
</style>
```

and the markup

```
<div id="header">
    <textarea id="lorem"></textarea>
    <button type="button" id="btn">Create list</button>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <ul>
        <li count="14" style="font-size: 260.294%; top: 200px; left: 100px;" class="word">apple</li>
        <li count="17" style="font-size: 300%; top: 154.03px; left: 184.147px;" class="word">iphone</li>
        <li count="3" style="font-size: 114.706%; color: rgb(60, 60, 60); top: 58.3853px; left: 190.93px;"class="word">launch</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 1.00075px; left: 114.112px;"class="word">sloppy</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 34.6356px; left: 24.3197px;"class="word">bertolucci</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 128.366px; left: 4.10757px;"class="word">world</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 196.017px; left: 72.0584px;"class="word">about</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 175.39px; left: 165.699px;"class="word">record</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 85.45px; left: 198.936px;"class="word">iphones</li>
        <li count="3" style="font-size: 114.706%; color: rgb(60, 60, 60); top: 8.88697px; left: 141.212px;"class="word">company</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 16.0928px; left: 45.5979px;"class="word">reports</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 100.443px; left: 0.000979345px;"class="word">related</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 184.385px; left: 46.3427px;"class="word">including</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 190.745px; left: 142.017px;"class="word">signal</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 113.674px; left: 199.061px;"class="word">where</li>
        <li count="5" style="font-size: 141.176%; color: rgb(36, 36, 36); top: 24.0312px; left: 165.029px;"class="word">phone</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 4.23405px; left: 71.2097px;"class="word">colleague</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 72.4837px; left: 3.86025px;"class="word">points</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 166.032px; left: 24.9013px;"class="word">there</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 198.87px; left: 114.988px;"class="word">users</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 140.808px; left: 191.295px;"class="word">perhaps</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 45.2271px; left: 183.666px;"class="word">product</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 0.00391736px; left: 99.1149px;"class="word">market</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 46.7167px; left: 15.378px;"class="word">would</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 142.418px; left: 9.44216px;"class="word">which</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 199.12px; left: 86.7648px;"class="word">getting</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 164.692px; left: 176.256px;"class="word">mobile</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 70.7861px; left: 195.638px;"class="word">devices</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 3.73941px; left: 127.091px;"class="word">other</li>
        <li count="3" style="font-size: 114.706%; color: rgb(60, 60, 60); top: 25.1942px; left: 33.6366px;"class="word">their</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 115.425px; left: 1.19684px;"class="word">multitasking</li>
        <li count="2" style="font-size: 101.471%; color: rgb(90, 90, 90); top: 191.474px; left: 59.5962px;"class="word">jbertolucci</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are using the top & left css attribute, you should have the css attribute position set to either absolute or relative. You are also using a non-existent HTML tag button, what you probably wanted to do was <input type="button" [...]>

Comment: What @HoLyVieR says. However, `<button>` does exist: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "does not wrap"? Can you show a screen shot?

Comment: I don't know if this matters (but it does break in IE I bet) but there is no space between your style and `class="word"` tag. That and I'd like to know what you mean by it does not wrap as well, does it have something to do with the li not having an absolute position set?

Comment: The code given wraps just fine, for me.  Not enough of the surrounding code or CSS was included.

Comment: Neat!  If you add `position:absolute` to the `li` style, his "tag cloud" makes a spiffy smoke ring. :P

Comment: i removed the position:absolute so as not to confuse the issue (though I think it did the opposite). I will include a screenshot of the weirdness. Thanks for the comments so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's wrapping. what browser are you using?

http://jsbin.com/avopu4/edit

Comment: He's obviously left off a key bit of CSS and/or HTML.  For fun, try adding `position: absolute` to the `<li>` CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to your style sheet and the list items will wrap correctly:

```
#main{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

This is a variant of the expanding box problem.

Comment: I used that css, but I don't want the words to break, just the sentence. So not "ap
ple boat car", but "apple
boat car". I f you get what I'm saying.

Answer (score -1):

full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>cloud generator</title>
<meta charset=utf-8">
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAALubzLxDPe376ukzxpz6qlRSeRrtKW42wftmgVeTHJfwF5iQHORSEne6ICdaMBMcnlC7OHYbOJMJ86Q" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
    google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.0");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $('#btn').click(function(){
        var lorem = $('#lorem').val();
        var uLorem = lorem.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g," ");    
        var aLorem = uLorem.split(" ");
        var oLorem = {};
        var min = 1;
        var max = 2;
        var count = 0;  

        for(var i = 0; i < aLorem.length; i++){
            var word = aLorem[i];

            if(word.length > 4){
                if(oLorem[word]){
                    oLorem[word]++;
                    count = oLorem[word];
                    if(count > max){
                        max = count;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    oLorem[word] = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        var index = 0;
        for(var val in oLorem){
            var m = oLorem[val];
            var r = (Math.floor(index/360)+1) * 100;

            if(m > 1){
                var $val = $("<li></li>")
                            .addClass("word")
                            .css({
                                "font-size": 150*(1.0+(1.5*m - max/2)/max) + "%",
                                "color": "rgb(" + 180/m + "," + 180/m + "," + 180/m + ")",
                                "top": r*Math.cos(index)+r,
                                "left": r*Math.sin(index)+r
                            }).
                            attr({
                                "count": m
                            })
                            .text(val);
                $('#main ul').append($val);
                index++;
            }
        }   
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#lorem{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
#main{

}
.word{
    margin: 5px;
}
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1>cloud generator</h1>
    <textarea id="lorem"></textarea>
    <button type="button" id="btn">Create cloud</button>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```